# NodeJS + MongoDB: find() with specific conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have no ideas how to do this, so I need your advice. I have form with 4 checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check_stain">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check_black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check_titan">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check_special">
```

I send data with simple submit, so if check_stain was checked, then req.body.check_stain will be "on", if not - "undefined".

In my db I have collection "companies", with several objects, every of which contains such schema:

```
{...
    "stain": "false",
    "black": "true",
    "titan": "false",
    "special": "true",
...}
```

values are simple strings. So, I need to get every object for which specified checkboxes are true (on), but not including ones that nones (undefined). In other words, I'd like to create a simple search algorithm. Let me give you an example: we check check_stain and we should get every object where stain is "true". Maybe other values will be "true"/"false" (doesn't matter). If we select check_stain and check_black, we get object with stain & black = "true", other fields are not interested.

I always find with such code:

```
collection.find({ %my-condition% } ,function(err, companies) {
    companies.each(function(err, company){
        //do smth with found
    });
});
```

But I have no idea how to write condition to find. I suppose, I should use $or operator in request. I read the docs, but I still can't get it. Thanks.

**UPDATE: Huh, that seems to be a solution of my problem:**

```
if (req.body.sort_query == 'req-steel') {
var condition = {}
if (req.body.check_stain == "on") {condition['stain'] = 'true';}
if (req.body.check_black == "on") {condition['black'] = 'true';}
if (req.body.check_titan == "on") {condition['titan'] = 'true';}
if (req.body.check_other == "on") {condition['special'] = 'true';}
for (var i in condition) {
    if (condition[i] != "true") {
        delete condition[i];
    }
}
var companies_list = new Array();
collection.find(condition, function (err, companies) {
    companies.each(function (err, company) {
        //do smth
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Where's the problem? Just create an object with the keys which are true and leave the others out.

Comment: not sure I've understand you correctly. Where should I create a new object, in database with collection.insert() or where? As I got it, you suggest to send this object as parameter for finding request or what?

Comment: `stain` should be `"true"`: `collection.find({ stain: "true" })` `stain` & `black` should be `"true"`: `collection.find({ stain: "true", black: "true" })`

Comment: well, I know, but how can I create a condition if I don't know which values are true? I shouldn't include false values in request, as you understand. The right will be smth like collection.find({ if(check_stain) stain: "true", if(check_black) black: "true" .... }) But as you know, I can't do such requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example black and stain are true:

```
var condition = {
    "stain": "false",
    "black": "true",
    "titan": "false",
    "special": "true",
}

for (var i in condition) {
    if (condition[i] != "true") {
        delete condition[i];
    }
}

collection.find(condition ,function(err, companies) {
    companies.each(function(err, company){
        //do smth with found
    });
});
```

[**Live condition DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/79ZGH/)

Comment: thank you, give me a few moments to examine you code. I still cant get how it works...

Comment: Just remove all keys which are not true from the condition object.

Comment: I've updated my post. Here's a code I've written. I've crossed my fingers and launched it :) Huh, it seems to be working properly :) Thank you very much!